# Finding the value of an analytic complex function while knowing some of its values

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to deal with this complex analysis question:

Assume that $f$ is analytic within $|z|<1$ and such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{n^2}{n+1}\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Find $f(\frac{\pi}{4})$

The limit of f while z approaches 0 is 1, and clearly $f({0})<1$ I suspect the solution could be extracted using the principle of the Minimum Modulus or any related theorem, but it seems I can't extract any more information out of the given assumptions.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to formulate it with a form of $1/n$. And if it's possible please update your question with Latex.

Comment: *Hint:* Substitute $z=1/n$ and think of the identity theorem ...

Comment: @MartinR Doesn't the identity theorem conclude that a function is 0 at an entire domain? Given the fact that we have values for f at many different points within the unit circle I struggle to find the two domains I need for the identity theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $g: B_1(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$,
$$
g(z) := 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{z(z+1)}\sin(z) &,~ z \neq 0 \\
1&, ~ z=0.
\end{cases}
$$
This is clearly differentiable on $B_1(0)\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. It is also differentiable in $0$, since
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{z(z+1)}\sin(z) = 1,
$$
i.e. $0$ is a removable singularity. So $g$ is holomorphic. The set $N := \lbrace n^{-1}:n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ has the accumulation point $0$ which lies in $B_1(0)$. Also observe that
$$
g\left( \frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{n^2}{n+1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n} \right).
$$
By the identity theorem, $f=g$. Now compute $g\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $z_n = 1/n$ with $n \in \Bbb N$ is
$$
 f(z_n) = \frac{1/z_n^2}{1/z_n + 1} \sin(z_n) = \frac{\sin(z_n)}{z_n(1+z_n)}
$$
or
$$
 z_n(1+z_n)f(z_n) - \sin(z_n) = 0
$$
Now use the identity theorem to conclude that $z(1+z)f(z) = \sin(z) 
$ for all $z$ in the unit disk, and use that to compute $f(\pi/4)$.